# CMG SDE Key Recovery will be required at this point

Tags: windows-7

I run Windows 7 on Dell PRECISION M4700 laptop. I allowed updating my operating system. After rebooting, I got a blue screen due to the update of a given driver. After some search, I follwed these [instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392). I mainly typed

```
error c0000001 loading backup
error c0000001 loading cache, attempting


error c0000001 loading alternate
error c0000001 loading alternate, attempting

So I got this error: CMG SDE Key Recovery will be required at this point
Booting continuing in xx seconds
```

What can I do to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

As you have a DELL PC/Laptop try this steps to restore the factory installation (if nothing other helps):

> To restore your computer to the original factory installation, follow
>   these steps:
>
> ```
> Turn on the computer, after the Dell logo press F8 key repeatedly until the
>     Advanced Boot Options menu (Advanced Startup Options).
> In Advanced Boot Options, highlight Repair Your Computer and press Enter.
> Click Next and logon to the administrator account in the computer.
> Click Dell DataSafe Restore and Emergency Backup and DataSafe Options.
> Choose Restore without preserving new or changed file. Click Next to continue.
> Choose Yes and click Next to continue.
> Progress status will appear. Click Restart to initiate the restoration process.
> ```

http://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/return-dell-precision-factory-default-19839.html

Comment: I did not define a restoration point before. My data is encrypted. If i retrieve it it will be useless since i won't have the key to decrypt it.

Comment: Never mind! There is a hidden partition on the HD where is stored the factory installation. Be aware you will be reset to fresh installation state!

Comment: I read the link you gave me, but my data is encrypted in Widnows 7, if i save it in a USB then i can not use it later

Comment: Good luck for you, Massinissa! You'll get it! :)